# How do we represent the Python/numpy function "zeros_like" in Julia language

Tags: julia

I am a bit new to Julia but I have some knowledge in Python. I am now learning Julia and I want to know how to represent the Python function "zeros_like" from Numpy in Julia.
The python code is below:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [3] #vector of one number
b = np.zeros_like(a)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Base.zero`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.zero) function returns the zero element (the *"additive identity element"* in the doc) for the type of its input argument:

```
julia> a = [3]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3

julia> zero(a)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
```

or

```
julia> zeros(Int, size(a))
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
```

Comment: `zero` is probably better, it returns with the same element type as the original array. `a = [3]; b = zero(a)`.

Comment: Indeed, it looks as if zero(a) does exactly what he wants it to do.

Comment: Wow! great. Since I had a vector and I wanted to replicate another vector with length the same as the original one, I have seen that zero() is also working.
So I had a = [1:10] and then I want aa = zero(a) which now works also well.

Comment: @KiruiKipngeno If what you want is to replicate a vector of the same size as the original, you may consider using [`similar`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.similar). The difference is `similar` will not initialize entries to zero.

Comment: @hckr similar will not initialize entries with zero and I want a vector with entries zero of the size of the original vector. That is why zero() and zeros() are the best options here.

Comment: @Bill: I suggest that you update your answer with the correct solution, `zero(a)`. Right now your answer is accepted, but is actually wrong, which is problematic.

Comment: @DNF Actually both answers give the same results.  With Bill's answer is more elaborative to new beginners, I suppose.

Comment: @kkirui No, the question is how to replicate the functionality of `np.zeros_like` from Numpy. The provided answer does not do that, only `zero(a)` provides the correct functionality, out of the alternatives offered. That should be in the answer itself, not left in a comment.

Comment: @DNF That is true. Bill should then edit the answer with zero()

Comment: @Bill It's good to see that you have updated your answer. There is still an error, though. Using `zero(a)` is correct, but you forgot to update the example output. It now shows `zero(a) => 0.0`, but the actual output is an integer.